# Can't connect to localhost from android emulator

Tags: android, asp.net, web-applications

Im running asp webapp on my local machine and am trying to access the same site from an android emulator.

I've tried changing the proxy settings to my local ip and 10.0.2.2
As well I've tried to connect directly to my local ip with still no luck.

Any input would be greatly appreciated;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be really painful to get this working.

You have to open up fire walls, and config IIS express - and you don't have the full IIS GUI for setup. So, by default, when running from Visual Studio, to get external use of that same web site can be REALLY a pain - a HUGE pain.

Best bet would be to install the full edition of IIS on your computer - and not use IIS express.

There are some ideas and suggesting here on how to open up IIS Express.

[Visual Studio 2017 - Giving remote users access to website in IIS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45986621/visual-studio-2017-giving-remote-users-access-to-website-in-iis-express)

Comment: Thank you so much! Definitely a huge pain trying to get this all squared away. Using Conveyor was the best solution to this and was working within a few minutes!